# How can I bundle all of my .scss files using my webpack.config.js file?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack

I'm trying to set up my `webpack.config.js` file to bundle my sass together. I have a file `src/sass/index.scss` that defines variables used elsewhere in the project. For example, my `src/components/css/button.scss` file uses the `$my-special-green` variable defined in the other file.

Is there way I can set up my `webpack.config.js` file to take my `/src` directory, find all of the `.scss` files recursively, and just bundle them into one `bundle.css` file? Ideally, I would like it all to happen in the `webpack.config.js` file.

I am able to require the individual `.scss` file in my `entry.js` file and that works, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Also, I understand that I could just import one `.scss` file into another, but I would also like to avoid that if possible.

if I *do* require the `.scss` file(s) in my `entry.js` file, they do get put in the `public/bundle.css` file that I am creating using `ExtractTextPlugin`, but I wonder if there is a way to have that happen based just off of this `webpack.config.js` file.

I thought that using

```
sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "src"))]
  }
```

might be the solution, but that doesn't really change anything in my case. I suppose that it really just ensures those paths are included when looking for the `.scss` files when requiring them in the javascript files?

my current `webpack.config.js` file looks like...

```
var path              = require('path');
var webpack           = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var SRC_PATH    = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
var BUILD_PATH  = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
var HTML_OPTS   = {
  filename: 'index.html',
  title:    'My Page Title',
  inject:   true,
  minify:   { collapseWhitespace: true, },
  templateContent: "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html>" +
      "<head>" +
        "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>" +
        "<meta charset='utf-8'/>" +
        "<title>{%= o.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %}</title>" +
      "</head>" +
      "<body>" +
      "</body>" +
    "</html>"
};

module.exports = {
  context:  SRC_PATH,
  entry:    [path.join(SRC_PATH, 'entry.js')],
  resolve:  {
    root:       SRC_PATH,
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output:   {
    path:       BUILD_PATH,
    filename:   'index.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(HTML_OPTS),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('public/bundle.css', {
            allChunks: true
        })
  ],
  module:   {
    loaders:  [
      {
        test:     /\.scss$/,
        loader:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
      },
      {
        test:     /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude:  /node_modules/,
        loader:   'babel',
        query:
          {
            presets:['react']
          }
      }
    ]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "src"))]
  }
};
```